# How to Mute output programmatically in powershell

Tags: powershell

i need help.

I need to change my code from CMD to powershell but i don't find any form to mute some output lines.

Here a fragment of my code from CMD:

```
REM ### Enable Debug ###
set DebuggingVar=0
REM ########################
REM ### Time to wait after Defrag ###
set Timer_advapi=600   REM Value in Seconds
REM #################################

IF NOT %DebuggingVar%==1    (
                            
                            Set Muted=^>nul
                            Set MutedAll=^>nul 2^>^&1
                            
                            )

reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dfrg\BootOptimizeFunction /v Enable /d Y /f %Muted%
```

^^^this works fine in CMD obviously.

I hope we understand the idea.
I create var called DebuggingVar to show all output of certain commands. But when DebuggingVar=0 the var, mute not necessary output in console.

I need to migrate to powershell.

I tried:

```
### Enable Debug ###

$DebuggingVar=0

####################


### Time to wait after Defrag ###

$Timer_advapi=600

#################################

IF ($DebuggingVar -eq 0) {

    $Muted = ">nul"
    $MutedAll = 'Out-Null'
}

Write-Host "Hola" | (Invoke-Expression $MutedAll) # THIS IS A SIMPLY EXAMPLE NOT WORKING // BAD SINTAX
```

But none of my tries work

Any ideas???

PD: Sorry for the post error/bad format. This is my first post!!!

Comment: what happens when you do `Write-Output "Holla" > $Null`

Comment: Hi Gerhard. Obviously work, but you don't understand the idea. I need to optionally $null, because a lot of command use $DebuggingVar

Comment: I tried:  

$DebuggingVar = $null  

write-host "hola" $DebuggingVar  

The output is only "hola"  

I tried:  
Write-host "hola" *>$DebuggingVar  
output is "hola".  

I lost, very lost in this problem.

Comment: what I am saying is, why do you need `Write-Host` and not `Write-Output`?

Comment: @Gerhard, is a simply example. I need other commands to mute like  
Like:
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /f "Windows Server" %Muted%  
or  
sc config defragsvc start= demand %Muted%

Comment: yes. I get that. muted where? to console? or other output?

Comment: @Gerhard. Yes, mute to don't show to user.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to use something like `Write-Verbose` instead.
Then you can change `$VerbosePreference` to **Continue** when you need to see the output.

You will then see all verbose output from commands that provide it, and have the ability to write your own statements to add extra information.

If you find that the verbose output is too much, you could switch to using `Write-Information` and changing `$InformationPreference` to **Continue** when you want to see the output. This way you can just write your own *debug* messages for the things you care about.

I would also use `Out-Null` everywhere to suppress output from other commands.

Comment: Hi @josh Wright. I not completelly understand your suggestion. But, this work for WMIC commands or non-native powershell commands???.  Because i need to use some non-native powershell commands for example schtasks or WMIC. Thanks!